# jQuery change and Ajax methods intermittently fail on IE and Firefox on Windows

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows, internet-explorer, firefox

I have been unable to replicate this error on my testing environments, but we have gotten regular calls from customers claiming that, essentially, a select menu `onChange` event fails to populate a second menu. They make a selection of the first menu, and it hangs without producing the second menu from which to complete the form.

I use the `change()` method assigned to the first select menu to run an Ajax request on the server to grab the second menu, which is populated with values based on what is selected in the first. I'm running jQuery 1.7.1 and this method succeeds in all of my testing environments.

These callers use Firefox and IE on Windows machines; so far, no calls from Mac users or Windows users with other browsers. I'd love to get more information from them, but these users are fairly inexperienced with even how to look for an error report in the browser. I have implemented the following fixes recommended in other solutions posted on StackOverflow and other boards, but still with no success:

- Disable the cache property in the Ajax calls
- Use the $('.selectMenu').change() method instead of $('.selectMenu').bind('change', function() { ... });
- Force HTTPS in the Ajax paths (since this is on a secure form)
- Check and ensure same-origin policy for Ajax calls
- Make sure the change() method ends with a `return false` to prevent jQuery from bubbling the event

With that, here's my code. It's fairly straightforward and consistent with standard examples of how to implement the jQuery `change()` and `ajax()` methods. There are two select menus. When the first one is selected, it runs an Ajax request on the server to obtain the content for the second menu, based on the value selected in the first.

```
$('#Sections').change(function() {
    $('#sectionsIndicator').css('display', 'block');
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://example.com/getCategoriesMenu',
        data: { id: $('#Sections').val() },
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#_categories').html(data);
            $('#sectionsIndicator').css('display', 'none');
            preview.update(); //render a preview of the whole form
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var msg = "It appears an error has occurred while trying to update the Categories menu.";
            msg += " Please try adjusting your security settings or refreshing this page before attempting to post this form.";
            msg += " [ Status: " + status + "   Error: " + error + " ]";
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The `data` value on a successful Ajax query is an HTML `<select>` menu. The `#_categories` selector corresponds to a `<div>` that is wrapped around the second select menu.

Like I said above, I'm unable to produce an error on all major browsers on the Mac, Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 environments. But I can't deny that users report the menu stalling once they try to make a selection.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon after `msg += " Please try adjusting your security settings or refreshing this page before attempting to post this form."` This may be causing a problem

Comment: That was my bad when transposing the code from the site to this post. (I've left out the exact error message to keep the code example agnostic of the site where it's hosted.) Consider the semicolon present in the live version.